# Sorting lowercase letters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, sorting, big-o

I am trying to convince myself that a counting sort performs faster than the sorted method in Python. However calling the sorted builtin seems to be faster even for large inputs like 10 million elements. What can I do to make the counting sort faster?

I generate a list of lowercase letters to simplify the example to 26 unique values:

```
letters = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(10000000)]
```

I then do the following variation on counting sort:

```
def sorted_count(letters):
 counts = [0] * 26
 for letter in letters:
     counts[ord(letter) - 97] += 1
 out = [None] * len(letters)
 j = 0
 for i in range(len(counts)):
     while counts[i] > 0:
         out[j] = chr(i + 97)
         counts[i] -= 1
         j += 1
 return out
```

Even on 10,000,000 elements the call to `sorted(letters)` is ~4x faster. 
How can I improve the speed of my sort?

Comment: Do you have the whole timeit script?

Comment: Also, you're comparing plain Python code with optimized C code. 4x slower really isn't bad, and might be considered "faster".

Comment: Are you asking about (theoretical) algorithmic improvements? Practically speaking, measuring performance of algorithms in pure python makes little sense. As @EricDuminil mentioned, the comparison with [built-in sort](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ebc5ce42a8a9e047e790aefbf9a94811569b2b6/Objects/listobject.c#L1978) (which is a comparison sort written in C) is invalid. For real-world usecases use a native language (possibly a C++ extension for python), go parallel, try GPUs, find structure in your input data that allows for faster edge-case handling etc.

Comment: Didn't consider the optimized C code. I think that's a great point.My question is about the Python specifics not theoretical improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a while loop inside the forloop at the end .
you could simple use

```
for i in range(len(counts)):
 if counts[i]>0:
     out[j] =counts[i]*chr(i + 97)
 j+=1
return out
```

Comment: Had to change it to this but did get a big bump in speed:out = []
    for i in range(len(counts)):
        out += list(counts[i] * chr(i + 97))

Comment: yeah i just gave the outline on how to do it, earlier it was having about O(n^2) complexity while counting sort actually has O(n+k) which is why its speed got reduced significantly

Comment: It's `counts`, not `count`. Also, `out` is now a list with 26 long strings and 9999974 `None`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified function, which is 3 times faster than the proposed one and twice as fast as `sorted`:

```
import random
import string
import timeit
N = 1000000
letters = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(N)]


def original_sorted_count(letters):
    counts = [0] * 26
    for letter in letters:
        counts[ord(letter) - 97] += 1
    out = [None] * len(letters)
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(counts)):
        while counts[i] > 0:
            out[j] = chr(i + 97)
            counts[i] -= 1
            j += 1
    return out

def eric(letters):
    counts = [0] * 26
    for letter in letters:
        counts[ord(letter) - 97] += 1
    out = []
    for i in range(len(counts)):
        out += [chr(i+97)] * counts[i]
    return out

print('Original : %.3fs' %timeit.timeit(lambda: original_sorted_count(letters), number=20))
print('Sorted   : %.3fs' %timeit.timeit(lambda: sorted(letters), number=20))
print('Eric     : %.3fs' %timeit.timeit(lambda: eric(letters), number=20))

print(eric(letters) == sorted(letters))
```

It outputs:

```
Original : 9.616s
Sorted   : 6.367s
Eric     : 3.604s
True
```